# Regex non-greedy OR

Tags: python, regex, django

Say I have 3 regular expressions A, B and C.

I need to match either A and B together or separately but always at least one.
C is optional.

My combined regex so far is A?B?C but if A and B doesn't match it still works.
I've tried A|BC however if A is matched, B is not evaluated and I need it to be evaluated.

```
(?P<param1>\d+)?(?P<param2>+\d+)?(?P<param3>\w+)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you expect it to differentiate between `param1` and `param2`? In the string `12345678912345` what should group `1`, `2` and `3` be? All characters match all groups so they will be consumed by the first one.

Comment: If the `django` tag means you're doing this in a URL config file, one simplifying approach would be to have two different patterns that share the same view - one with A and B required, one with A or B required. I think there are other options but I'd have to see the actual regexp with the divider between A and B included.

Comment: @OGHaza if you look closely there is a '+' sign separating the two.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper thanks for the solution. If I will not find an all-in-one solution I will use this. Or return a 404 from inside the view if both param1 and param2 are None

Comment: @andrei, ah very sneaky ;) Just so you're aware `\w+` also captures numbers. If you know param3 will not start with a number then it doesn't really matter, but if it could start with a number you will get incorrect results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?:A(?:B)?|B)(?:C)?
```

---

#### UPDATE:

If you need to use each of `A`, `B` and `C` only once, go with

```
((?:A)?(?:B)?)(?!\1{100})(?:C)?
```

which is not 100% correct, but should cover 99.99+% of all possibilities

Comment: How would you do this with named groups? Each named group can be defined only once.

Comment: Wow, this actually works but I have no idea how. I thought (?:) doesn't capture any values.

Answer (score 0):

You could match three alternatives: `(AB|A|B)`, but this *does* require that you capture 4 different groups; two for the `A` and `B` case, and one each for the `A` or `B` cases. Your code extracting the captured groups will have to take this into account:

```
(?:(?P<param1_and>\d+)(?P<param2_and>+\d+)|(?P<param1_or>\d+)|(?P<param2_or>+\d+))(?P<param3>\w+)
```

and you'd have to look for `param1_and` or `param1_or` and `param2_and` or `param2_or` in the captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly as it is, maybe this would work?

```
(?P<possibly_joined_params>\d+\+\d+|\d+|\+\d+)(?P<param3>\w+)?
```

And then in your view, try splitting on '+':

```
def someview(request, possibly_joined_params, param3=None):
    param_parts = possibly_joined_params.split('+')
    if len(param_parts) == 1:
        param1 = param_parts[0]
        param2 = ''
    else:
        param1, param2 = param_parts
```

I'm not sure that's cleaner than the idea of just having two patterns to match the view, though.